# Script that finds and moves all .c and .cc files unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to make a script using bash to locate and move all .c and .cc files. The path can be different if the user wants it to be.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Give me path if you want"
read -t 10 ANS
if [ -z "$ANS" ]; then
find ~/testfiles2 \( -name "*.c" -o -name ".cc" \) -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;
else
find ~/testfiles2 \( -name "*.c" -o -name ".cc" \) -exec mv -i '{}' $ANS \;
fi
```

The error that I got is "No such file or directory".

Also when I run `find ~/testfiles2 \( -name "*.c" -o -name ".cc" \) -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;` it runs but moves only `.cc` files.

Comment: You need a space before `\;`

Comment: Also before `\)`

Comment: I have spaces at my code but by mistake didnt added them here. But thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first error, `No such file or directory`, is likely due to the target directory you want to move files to not existing - can you try creating that directory (e.g. `mkdir target`), then running the command (providing `target` as the input)?

Your second command is not working because you have a few typos; first, you need to have a space inserted between parentheses and their contents, so `...-name ".cc"\)` should be `...-name ".cc" \)`. Second, with the selector for .cc files you are not matching anything except for files literally named ".cc" -- I think you've missed the wildcard for that one. Actually, I would expect that this command as written would only move .c files, and skip .cc files (other than files literally called .cc).
Fixing the space issue and the wildcard issue, you probably want something that looks like:

```
find ~/testfiles2 \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cc" \) -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;
```

This is assuming that your `~/destination` directory already exists.

Finally, this can be accomplished a little more succinctly by using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with find! Rather than matching via name, we match via regex:

```
find ~/testfiles2 -iregex '.*\.\(c\|cc\)$' -exec mv -i '{}' ~/destination \;
```

This might look complicated, but here's how it works out:

- `.*` says match a single character 0 or more times; here the `.` is not a literal period, but the regular expression placeholder for a single character, and `*` says "match the preceding character 0 or more times". This part of the expression will match the start of filenames, leading up to their extension
- `\.` says match the literal period character - we have to "escape" the character by preceding it with a backslash to tell `find` that this character should be interpreted literally, not as its regular expression value (of matching any character)
- `\(c\|cc\)` this looks crazier than it should because we have to do some escaping here; a regular expression like (c|cc) would match the character `c` or the characters `cc`; the `|` pipe character delimits the different possible matches. You can add as many as you'd like there, e.g. if you wanted to match mp4s as well you could do (c|cc|mp4). However, in order to tell `find` to interpret the parentheses `()` and pipe `|` as special-meaning regular expression characters, we need to escape those as well, leaving us with `\(c\|cc\)`
- `$` this regular expression character matches the end of the line

Taken together, this will match all file prefixes (`.*`) that end in .c or .cc.

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer! I hope you post more like this.